# Failed to load plugin: advlink from url

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I am trying to load `advlink` plugin by following installation instructions given on [official documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/plugins/Plugin3x@advlink/) site.
I have found this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
  theme : "advanced",
  mode : "textareas",
  plugins : "advlink"
});
```

Unfortunately there is not such directory like "advlink" in `path_tinymce/plugins/`

I have searched in google over and over also in `stackoverflow` directory. Result: nothing to solve the problem.

*Note: I am using*  `version 4.7.5`

I'll appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you reference is from TinyMCE 3.x.  The `advlink` plugin did exist in TinyMCE 3.x but is no longer part of TinyMCE in TinyMCE 4.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/

Comment: Can you tell me how we can get advanced tab for link in v-4.

Comment: This is the sole link plugin for TinyMCE 4:  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/link/

Comment: I got it. I need to develop the thing using their api.